# Breakpoints in Intellij during remote debugging not working

Tags: java, intellij-idea, breakpoints, remote-debugging

I'm trying to debug a Spring Boot microservice using Intellij's remote debugging feature. I have followed the correct steps to connect to the Cloud Service (like enabling ssh) where the service is deployed, and have set up the correct Intellij configuration under "Remote JVM Debug".

The method I'm trying to debug is a Spring Boot `RequestMapping` (`GET`) controller method. I added in my breakpoints in this method, but as soon as I hit the debug button and visit the associated path (same as the `RequestMapping`'s `path` value) in the UI in the browser, the breakpoints don't seem to work as the method execution never steps. Instead, the red breakpoint dots are somehow replaced with green checkmarks, like below -

[image: Breakpoints before]

[image: Breakpoints after]

What does this indicate? Any idea as to why the debugging doesn't work? Even print statements in the method aren't displayed in the console.

Comment: Which UI theme are you using? And which version of IDEA?

Comment: Material Theme Darker from this [Jetbrains Material Theme UI Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8006-material-theme-ui). Version of IDEA - `2021.2.2`.

Comment: What do the breakpoints look like if you use the default theme? (I don't think that theme is from Jetbrains, by the way)